# wrong rep on SE sites when linking your profile?

Tags: support

I am on [gamedev at stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1047/acidzombie24). My rep was 1 then + 100 for linking my profile. I asked a question and got 6upvotes and it has been a few days so logically i should have 131 rep shouldnt i? i am still at 101. Its like it is ignoring my rep until i earn enough to surpass the bonus rep for linking an account.

Answer (score 4):

You marked the question community wiki in [revision 2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/1583/revisions); you [don't earn rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741) from community wiki questions (or answers posted on community wiki questions)

Comment: ahh, what happen was i posted an answer on another site which was CW as well and i didnt get it there either. That explains it.